# Problems with the visualisation of large networks in Networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I have a large Python dataframe from which I am trying to build a network. I have a `source_node` (with around 10 unique values) and a target_node (with thousands of values). I am looking at outgoing interactions of e.g. `source_node_1` to multiple target nodes. Currently, my visualisation of the network is not ideal, to say the least.

This is what the result looks like:

[image: what the result looks like]

This is the code used to create the network:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'source_node':['sc1','sc2','sc2'],
    'target_node':['tg1,tg2,tg3','tg10','tg2,sc1']
}) 
df['splitted_targets'] = df['target_node'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))

G = nx.DiGraph()

for r in df.iterrows():
    for user in r[1]['splitted_targets']:
        G.add_edge(r[1]['source_node'], user)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

Is there a simple way to e.g. create 10 graphs for each unique `source_node` and its `target_nodes`, or otherwise create a simplified graph that can be read?

Comment: You would probably need to partition the graph and plot each of the partitions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is logical that so huge graph looks like a horrifying mess. On FullHD monitor with 5000 nodes for every node one will have not more than:

`sqrt(1920 * 1080 / 5000) = 20`

An image of 20x20 pixels for node, text label and all possible edges. Moreover, the human brain [is very bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_memory#Capacity) in manipulating [with this amount of data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magical_Number_Seven,_Plus_or_Minus_Two) so, even if one will draw the huge graph, he will not able to analyze it properly.

In your case you have very little amount of source nodes and thousand of target nodes for each source node. You can **greatly** decrease the size of your graph if you will just remove all target nodes that are linked to only one source node (remember that you will still have this info and you can analyze it later with just printing all target nodes corresponding to particular source node):

```
G.remove_nodes_from([
    n
    for n in G.nodes
    if n not in df['source_node']
    if G.degree(n) < 2
])
```

So the final code will be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'source_node':['sc1','sc2','sc3'],
'target_node':['tg1,tg2,tg3,sc2','tg10,tg2,sc3','tg2,sc1'] }) 

df['splitted_targets'] = df['target_node'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))

G = nx.DiGraph()
for r in df.iterrows():
    for user in r[1]['splitted_targets']:
        G.add_edge(r[1]['source_node'], user)
print(list(list(G.neighbors(n)) for n in G.nodes))
G.remove_nodes_from([
    n
    for n in G.nodes
    if n not in df['source_node']
    if G.degree(n) < 2
])
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

And this graph:

[image]

Will be reduced to:

[image]

I am sure that in your case it will help a lot because you have only several dozens of source nodes. You can also play with node sizes, node labels, fonts etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vurmux, it looks a lot better! The source nodes are in the middle now. Now I was trying to create a subgraph that would plot all of the connections of the source_node_1, for example. Like that: `H = nx.Graph(((source_node, splitted_targets) for source_node,splitted_targets in G.edges(data=True) if source_node == 'source_node_1'))
nx.draw(H,with_labels=True,node_size=3000)
plt.show()`. But I get a NetworkXError ("Input is not a valid edge list"). Do you have an idea what's missing?

Comment: You can't use networkx nodes/edges to create new graph (without additional preparing). Use `G.subgraph()`: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.subgraph.html#networkx.DiGraph.subgraph

Comment: I used G.subgraph, but I only get one source_node that I specify in the graph, it's just one dot. The connections are missing. `selected_nodes = [source_node for source_node,splitted_targets in G.nodes(data=True) if source_node == 'source_node_1'] H = G.subgraph(selected_nodes)
nx.draw(H,with_labels=True,node_size=3000)`. Do you know what the problem is here?

Comment: You need to pass all nodes you want to visualize to `G.subgraph` in arguments.